# съезжает разметка с сообщения в телеграм aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Когда я хочу отметить множество пользователей:

```
for i, (user_id, message_date, username) in enumerate(inactive_users, start=1):
            result += f"{i}. [{username}](tg://user?id={user_id}) ({days_passed(message_date)})\n"
```

то, при отправке сообщения(`await msg.answer(result, parse_mode="MarkDown")`) съезжает разметка и получается что-то вроде:

1. **nnn** (0)
2. **Анатолий** (0)
3. **гейл** (0)
4. InKo**rchik (0)**
5. AUNt**ik (0)**
6. Menc**hik (0)**
   и тд.

*P.S. жирный текст это кликабельная часть сообщения*

т.е. после третьего места она съезжает на 4 символа везде далее

Как мне это исправить?(В интернете ничего не нашел)